# Remove NULL, moving cell up MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on something new and I can't get out of this point.

I created a new table called week, with the columns mon, tue.

I can't find an alternative to remove the empty spaces and move the cell up.

```
-- create a table
CREATE TABLE semana (
  seg VARCHAR(30),
  ter VARCHAR(30)
);

-- insert some values
INSERT INTO semana VALUES ('aa', '');
INSERT INTO semana VALUES ('', 'tt');
INSERT INTO semana VALUES ('' , 'bb');
-- fetch some values

SELECT seg, ter FROM semana  ORDER BY semana . seg, ter
```

The output I get:

[image]

THE OUTPUT I WANT TO RECEIVE

[image]

Comment: Why have you got two separate tables with the same field in them to begin with? If you have two tables with the same design this is usually a sign of bad database design, and it can start to lead to problems like you're seeing now. _Probably_ you want _one_ "cities" table with 2 columns - "city" and "category" (or some other name which is appropriate to whatever meaning you're ascribing to the table names).

Comment: Looks like you want a spreadsheet, not an RDBMS.

Comment: @ADyson I was testing new formats here, and reformulating the question, I believe it has become more decent

Comment: But Seg's AA has no relation to Ter's BB, so why do you care if they are on the same row in your output? This isn't how one uses relational databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, as pointed out by [@ADyson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5947043/adyson), [@Bill Karwin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20860/bill-karwin) and [@Isolated](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13118009/isolated), you can't do that in a relational database! They work in a fundamentally different way from spreadsheets.

A better design would be to have a table called *calendar*, with a proper grain defined (let's say day), then you can provide further hierarchies (i.e. other columns, like *week_day*, *is_weekend*, etc). That works great for an OLAP (analytical) design requirement.

In an OLTP (transactional) database design, you'll probably want to split this calendar table into different tables to enhance performance and management, a process called normalization  [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

```sql
CREATE TABLE calendar (
  dt_date DATE,
  week_day VARCHAR(30),
  is_weekend BOOLEAN
);

-- insert some values
INSERT INTO calendar VALUES ('2023-02-24', 'Sexta-feira', FALSE);
INSERT INTO calendar VALUES ('2023-02-25', 'Sábado', TRUE);
INSERT INTO calendar VALUES ('2023-02-26', 'Domingo', TRUE);

SELECT * FROM calendar;
```

| dt_date | week_day | is_weekend |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-24 | Sexta-feira | false |
| 2023-02-25 | Sábado | true |
| 2023-02-26 | Domingo | true |